# WPF RTP Streaming

Tags: c#, wpf, rtp

I am currently in the process of writing an application that will receive an RTP Video Stream from a VLC Client. I am hoping to implement this in WPF and so have been looking for any solutions online to help me. So far I've skimmed over Live555 RTP Streaming and considering the possibility of embedding a VLC client into the WPF Application. I also looked at WpfMediaKit but I could not get that to work properly, which is probably my own fault.

I am just wondering if it is at all possible to do the video streaming over RTP purely through WPF or will I have to make use of an external library.

Thanks, Stuart.

Comment: Incase anyone searches for a solution to this I have done it by embedding an Active X VLC control into a Windows Control Form the embedded all that into a WPF application and that is working a treat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had with the ActiveX control in a WPF environment is that it is placed in a Windows Forms Host control which meant that it will always be rendered on top of everything else, not allowing me to put overlay any media controls.

You should take a look at VlcDotNet [here](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/). It is a wrapper for the VLC dll's and is quite easy to use.